# In the auto.arima() function in R, how do I find the p,d,q values for that arima

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I used an R code with an `auto.arima` function on a time series data set to forecast. From here, Id like to know how to find the p,d,q values for the arima. Is there a quick way to determine that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forecast::auto.arima()` function was written to pick the optimal p, d, and q with respect to some optimization criterion (e.g. AIC). If you want to see which model was picked, use the `summary()` function.

For example:

```
fit <- auto.arima(lynx)
summary(fit)
```

> ```
> Series: lynx 
>   ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean 
>   Coefficients:
>          ar1      ar2      ma1      ma2       mean
>       1.3421  -0.6738  -0.2027  -0.2564  1544.4039
> s.e.  0.0984   0.0801   0.1261   0.1097   131.9242
> sigma^2 estimated as 761965:  log likelihood=-932.08
> AIC=1876.17   AICc=1876.95   BIC=1892.58
> Training set error measures:
>                     ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
> Training set -1.608903 853.5488 610.1112 -63.90926 140.7693 0.7343143 -0.01267127
> ```

Where you can see the particular specification in the second row of the output. In this example, `auto.arima` picks an ARIMA(2,0,2).

Note that I did this naively here for demonstration purposes. I didn't check whether this is an accurate representation of the dependency structure in the `lynx` data set.

Answer (score 2):

Other than `summary()`, you could also use `arimaorder(fit)` to get the vector `c(p,d,q)` or `as.character(fit)` to get `"ARIMA(p,d,q)"`.